# How to get the subclass reference in Activity

Tags: java, android

I have class called Test in which I have one method which is taking Activity as one parameter ,

```
public class Test{
  Activity activity;
  public void someMethod(Activity _activity)
  {
    activity = _activity;
  }
}
```

and suppose this is called from the class MainActivity like :

```
 test.someMethod(this)
```

here I am passing my activity MainActivity to class Test . And it is being catcher in its supper class Activity . How can I know the type of Activity that is its subclass (here it is MainActivity) and cast it to the MainActivity ?

Comment: @james: and how should be context used for calling the method of that class

Answer (score 0):

with `instanceof`:

```
 if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {}
```

Comment: No I don't have MainActivity accessible because my Test class code will go into library .

Comment: @V-Xtreme If not accessible then how you can subclass??

Comment: @PankajKumar : I have subclass using Activity not MainActivity .

Comment: @V-Xtreme I think you are doing impossible task. Think once about your logic

Comment: @PankajKumar :yeah! may be :)